# flutter pub get : - fstore depends on inspireui from path which depends on async 2.8.1, async 2.8.1 is required

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

*Because fstore depends on inspireui from path which depends on async 2.8.1, async 2.8.1 is required.
So, because fstore depends on async 2.6.1, version solving failed.*

**please help to resolve the problem , tried by adding
async: 2.8.1
video_player: 2.1.5
in pubspec.yaml**